# How ifstream acts differently than cin in c++?

Tags: c++, io

When we use `cin>>input;`, space is used for terminating statement, however if we use the following code

```
ifstream fin("myfile.dat");
char ch;
while( !fin.eof( ) )
{
    fin>>ch;
};
fin.close();
```

If "Hello World!" is stored in myfile.dat, then this function will output "HelloWorld!", instead of "Hello". Now, my question is why the loop didn't end when it encountered space, as it happened in the when using cin>>input;

Comment: It didn't end at `"Hello` because you used a loop? If there was no loop, you'd only get `"Hello`.

Comment: What's `input` in `cin>>input;`? The `ifstream` code reads every single character till the end of file, a whitespace is a character. Also your code does not output anything at all, it simply reads everything 1 by 1 and discards it.

Comment: I've formatted your code. In the next post please properly format your code.

Comment: That code doesn't output anything at all. (And it's not a function.)

Comment: And, please, always use `fin.eof()` after file reading trying.

Comment: Thanks for Answering, bolov i am new to stackoverflow, for me i didnt see any option for formatting, i just wrote it down

Comment: If you use `fin >> input` you'll get the same behavior as you saw in `std::cin >> input`. If you replace `fin` in the code in the question with `std::cin` you'll see the same behavior as you see in the code as written.